# Delete bulk posts

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to delete a lot posts in bulk from a category which have more than 1000 posts. I prefer to do them in SQL. Where I put a single command and I see the posts vanished ;)

How is it possible to achieve this?

Somebody told me to do this to check the posts I want to delete, but it didn't work! (I want to delete between posts ID 100 to 200).

> SELECT * FROM ((wp_posts p LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON p.ID
>   = tr.object_id)  LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)  LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id WHERE t.name='xxx' and p.ID>=100 and p.ID<=200

Thanks!

Comment: Well, this is a `SELECT` statement, so it's not going to *delete* anything.  Are you just looking for the syntax of a `DELETE` statement?

Comment: or maybe you should consider using an UPDATE statement to set a "deleted" flag and schedule the real deletion to be performed later by another process

Comment: Hello. Yes I know. But when I use it, I see nothing at all. Not the posts. But before I use "delete" I want to see the posts.

Comment: *"But it didn't work"* doesn't meet SO's requirement of stating the exact expected result, the exact actual result, and the difference between the two. Please read topics at StackOverflow.com/help to learn about criteria that Questions and Answers must meet. You can `edit` to add the info necessary to avoid deletion by the platform. This info is necessary for visitors to *efficiently* and *definitively* be able to fully understand, & ultimately help solve, your issue, which could in turn help others solve similar issues of their own.

Answer (score 0):

Your select query allows you to follow buddy's advice so you can look at the records before you delete them.  If you are happy with what you see, change "select *" to "delete".

Comment: Thanks. But when I use "select" I don't see anything at all. I don't see the posts, even though, there are posts and the category ID is right.

Answer (score 0):

Here the the command which you can use to delete thousands of posts within seconds. If you use any plugin, It will not work and server timeout issue will occur.

```
DELETE FROM wpxo_posts WHERE post_type = 'post'
```

If you want to delete posts then use this command, If you want to delete custom post types then replace last word 'post' with your custom post type.

**Here is how you can check your post type,**

```
/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=posts
```

Go to Control Panel > phpmyadmin > select your database and use this query.